# Create a View from Multiple Tables which Have Some Columns in Common

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have 3 tables. TableA has 10 columns, TableB has 15 columns and TableC has 20 columns. Columns 1-5 are the common in all 3 tables (although the data are unique in each table). The other columns are unique to their respective tables.
I want to create a view which will have all the unique columns from all 3 tables and the 5 columns common to all 3. The view should have 35 columns (5 common, 30 unique) and all the data from all 3 tables.

Is this possible?

I have tried various unions but none of them give me the result that I am looking for.

Thanks!

As an example, below is what I am looking to do. I want to combine Tables A, B and C into a view that I have shown below. Thank you

Example tables and desired view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXZ3N.png

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.  Your description is not clear.

Comment: i added an image to the original question showing how I am looking to combine the tables into a view. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use null as column_name to match the number of columns.

Example:

```
create table tab1(a int,b int,c int);

create table tab2(a int,b int,d int,e int);

select a ,b , c, null as d, null as e
from tab1
union all
select a ,b , null as c, d,e
from tab2;
```